# getting error "java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to" when i m trying API on android device. But it is working on "Postman"

Tags: android, rest

i am trying to call certain API, which is working fine if i test it on laptop(postman) but when i use it in my app its gives exception.

```
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.add("comapanyName",jsonObject.getString("company_name"));

        AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
        asyncHttpClient.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        asyncHttpClient.post(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                String s = new String(responseBody);
                Log.i("RESPONSE_INSERT", s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                    Log.i("RESPONSE_ERROR_I", e.getMessage());

            }
        });
```

Its not local API but on server

Comment: check this :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36811386/7319704

Comment: as i said, its not localhost api but on live server

Comment: for some reason your device has no access to your server.

Answer (score 3):

Did you add your internet permissions in your Manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: i have already given this permission as many other APIs are working just fine in this app

Comment: Can you post your logcat of the error you are getting?

Comment: `java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /139.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx`

Comment: It seems like you are connecting to an external IP outside your current LAN network, make sure that if you server is hosted externally using a port that the incoming IP / Range is allowed on your server. You can check PHP.ini guides out there, there are many of them.