# NativeScript Angular Cleartext HTTP traffic to localhost not permitted

Tags: android, angular, xml, typescript, nativescript-angular

I am working with angular version of native script and trying to create a login system to my network.
Below is my code that attempts to log into the network.

home.component.ts

```
 import { LoginService } from '../Services/login/login.service';
 export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

 public user: User;
 loginForm: FormGroup;

 constructor(private router: Router,
     private userService: UserService,
     private page: Page,
     public  loginDetails: LoginDetails,
     private LoginService: LoginService

 ) {

     this.user = new User();
     this.user.email = "m@m.com";
     this.user.password = "pass123";
     this.user.logo = "~/Images/opos_logo.png";
 }

 submit() {

    /* set a user variable with data from the formGroup */
    const user: string = this.user.email;
    /* set a password variable with data from the formGroup */
    const password: string = this.user.password;

    this.LoginService.loginUser(user, password)
        .subscribe(data => this.checkUser(data));
 }
}
```

Services/login/login.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Jwt } from '../../Classes/jwt';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {


  loginUrl = 'http://localhost/Login.w';

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  loginUser(user, pass) {
      return this._http.get<Jwt>(
          this.loginUrl, { params: { fi_user: user, fi_pass: pass } });
  }
}
```

When I tried to run my app like this I would get the following error:

"originalStack": "Error: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to localhost not permitted\n at new ZoneAwareError        (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:1298:31)\n at onRequestComplete     (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/http/http-request/http-request.js:54:30)\n at Object.onComplete (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/http/http-request/http-request.js:43:7)"

To tried to fix the issue by following the suggestions on the post [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted/50834600) and followed the advice on that post. 
I added a androidmanifest.xml file to my program (this was not already part of the application as such I am not sure if the application is accessing the file) on the path /App_Resources/Android/AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="__PACKAGE__"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="__APILEVEL__"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">

    <activity
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>
</application>
```

I also added a network_security_config.xml file which the Stack overflow post was suggesting to the path res/xml/network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
   <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
      <domain includeSubdomains="true">domain.com (to be adjusted)</domain>
   </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I also tried to add the application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tag to my home.component.html to fix the error but this did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
loginUrl = 'http://10.0.2.2/Login.w';
```

I just have read article: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48591525
@EdwardGarson wrote:

> From the emulator, localhost or 127.0.0.1 refers to the emulator itself, not your local machine. You need to use ip 10.0.2.2, which is bridged to your local machine.

Greetings